# How to get a Kodak EasyShare C713 to show up as a drive?

Tags: windows-xp

My mom recently bought a used Kodak EasyShare C713. She used to transfer photos as usual, by removing the SD card, but this she found this awkward due to the fact that card is kept in the battery compartment (the batteries often fall out when doing so), so she would prefer to use the cable.

The problem is she uses Picasa to manage her photos and there doesn't seem to be any other way of transferring the photos other than through the Kodak EasyShare software. The camera doesn't appear in My Computer nor in "Scanners and Cameras". Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the EasyShare software and reboot, then plug the device in and let Windows install it's own drivers. The camera should show up as a **Mass Storage Device** (it's own drive) in **My Computer** once you plug it in.

Comment: Thanks, there was an issue with the cable not working but this solution worked in the end.